# On the injective dimension of a module

Tags: commutative-algebra, ring-theory, modules, homological-algebra

Let $R$ be a ring and $M$ an $R$-module then

inj dim $M\leq i\in\mathbb{N}$ if and only if $\mathrm{Ext}^{i+1}(N,M)=0$ for every cyclic module $N$.

The implication from left to right is obvious, I'm finding some difficulties in proving the other implication. In case we need it I think we can suppose $M$ finitely generated and $R$ noetherian. Do you have any suggestions fot the implication I'm missing?

Comment: This reminds me of Baer's criterion.

Comment: At any rate, use Schanuel's lemma to do "dimension shifting", and it should follow from Baer's criterion. An outline is in Lam section 5C, but this specific result is not there.

Comment: thank you, that helped, I posted an answer following you suggestions, hope it's right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following exact sequence:

$0\rightarrow M\rightarrow I^0\rightarrow I^1\rightarrow\cdots\rightarrow I^{i-2}\rightarrow I^{i-1}\rightarrow M^\prime\rightarrow0$

where the $I^j$'s are injectives and $M^\prime=\mathrm{coker}(I^{i-2}\rightarrow I^{i-1})$. Then by dimension shifting $0=\mathrm{Ext}^{i+1}(N,M)=\mathrm{Ext}^1(N,M^\prime)$. So if $N=R/J$ then the exact sequence $0\rightarrow J\rightarrow R\rightarrow R/J\rightarrow 0$ yields an exact sequence

$0\rightarrow\mathrm{Hom}(R/J,M^\prime)\rightarrow\mathrm{Hom}(R,M^\prime)\rightarrow\mathrm{Hom}(J,M^\prime)\rightarrow0$ (because $\mathrm{Ext}^1(N,M^\prime)=0$). So by Baer's criterion $M^\prime$ is injective (because $\mathrm{Hom}(R,M^\prime)\rightarrow\mathrm{Hom}(J,M^\prime)$ is surjective for every ideal $J$).

Comment: Looks good to me. :-)